# Distribution of the minimum among $N$ random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, order-statistics

I read this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-iid-random-variables-distributed where I can find how to compute the density distribution of the minimum among $N$ positive random variables. If the cumulative of these random variables is $F(x)$ the cumulative of the minimum among $N$ of these random variables is:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\text{min}\le x)=1-\big(1-F(x)\big)^N$$

From this result it is easy to compute the mean value of the minimum (simply using integration by parts):
$$ 
\overline{\text{min}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\,\frac{d \mathbb{P}(\text{min}\le x)}{dx}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\big(1-F(x)\big)^Ndx
$$
At this point I can compute $\overline{\text{min}}$ for a general cumulative distribution $F(x)$.

I want now to get the scaling of $\overline{\text{min}}$ for $N\rightarrow\infty$ when $F(x)=\frac
{1}{r!}\int_{0}^{x}l^re^{-l}dl$ for $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r>-1$. (A simple case can be the one for $r=0$, that is the density distribution for the variables is exponential, in this case the average min value scale as $1/N$).
In the general case I can arrive to:
$$
\overline{\text{min}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{r!}\int_0^{x}l^re^{-l}dl\right)^Ndx
$$
but I don't know how to approximate it. For general $r$ it can be useful to approximate $\frac{l^re^{-l}}{r!}\simeq \frac{l^r}{r!}\propto l^r$, since the important contribution for the average minimum value will be $\ll1$. In this approximation my result is:
$$
\overline{\text{min}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\int_0^{x}l^rdl\right)^Ndx
$$ but still can't figure out which is the scaling with large $N$.

The result should be:
$$
\overline{\text{min}}\simeq N^{-\frac{1}{r+1}}
$$

I am studying the following paper: https://hal.science/jpa-00232897/document .

Here the authors find the scaling of the mean value of what I suppose is the minimum of the random variables, which in this case are $l_{ij}$, called “distances”. I cannot find the scaling found after Eq.(5), can anyone help me?

Comment: $l^re^{-l}$ is not a density unless you renormalise it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to divide by $r!$, I'll correct the question. The fact is that I'm interested only on the scaling for large $N$, that's why I forgot it.